# How make UICollectionView with 2 columns, different cells heights but with equal margins (all 4)?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, height, cells, margins

I have one problem with UICollectionView. I need to make UICollectionView with these properties:

1. All cells in UICollectionView have same width.
2. Cells in UICollectionView do NOT have same height.
3. UICollectionView have two columns.
4. All margins between all cells must be the 20px.

I can not implement 2 and 4 in the same time. Just colour cells (no need to put any object in cells).

I need solution in Swift.

Here is screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM8VQ.png and my code:

```
let imagesNames = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setUpUI()
}

func setUpUI(){

    let flowLayoutForCV = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    flowLayoutForCV.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width * 0.03, bottom: 10, right: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width * 0.03)


    let cV = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height), collectionViewLayout: flowLayoutForCV)
    cV.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cV.dataSource = self
    cV.delegate = self
    cV.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellID")
    self.view.addSubview(cV)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return imagesNames.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellID", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let red: CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)) / 255.0
    let green: CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)) / 255.0
    let blue: CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)) / 255.0
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width * 0.455, height: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(250)) + 50)
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: I added screenshot and code.

Comment: Did you find any solution for it?